# Archimedean Property/ Axiom of Completeness

Tags: real-analysis

I was wondering if anyone could answer this for me. I am kind of confused on this?

Explain the meaning of the Archimedean Property and how does this result from the Axiom of Completeness?

Answer (score 2):

Let $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$, with 
$x > 0$. Suppose that no positive integral multiple of $x$ exceeds $y$, and let
$S = \{nx : n \in \mathbb{Z}^+ \}$. Then $y$ is, by assumption, an upper bound for $S$. Let
$u = \sup S$, the least upper bound of $S$. Consider the element $u-\frac{1}{2}x$. This,
being $< u$, is not an upper bound. Use this to produce an element of $S$
greater than $u$, thus reaching a contradiction.

Comment: Did you think to produce element greater than $y$? Because we assumed there is no integral multiple of x that is greater than $y$ we should prove the converse at the end.